# Valgrind detects memory leak at fclose()

Tags: c++, valgrind, fclose

Why does valgrind say I've got memory leak at the `fclose()` call?

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Stream
{
    public:
        Stream();
        ~Stream();
    private:
        char*  pszOutput;
        size_t size;
        FILE* file;
};

Stream::Stream()
{
    file = open_memstream(&pszOutput, &size);
}

Stream::~Stream()
{
    fclose(file);
}

int main()
{
    Stream s;   

    return 0;
}
```

Valgrind report:

```
==52387== 1 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==52387==    at 0x4C28CCE: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:632)
==52387==    by 0x5639CA3: _IO_mem_finish (memstream.c:132)
==52387==    by 0x5635956: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:66)
```

Does it matter to initialize `pszOutput` or `size`? Or maybe I need to add something else?

Comment: did you try to free(pszOutput); ?

Answer (score 3):

From : http://linux.die.net/man/3/open_memstream

> The open_memstream() function opens a stream for writing to a buffer. The buffer is dynamically allocated (as with malloc(3)), and automatically grows as required. After closing the stream, the caller should free(3) this buffer.

So according to this you need to **free(pszOutput)** after your file descriptor is closed.

Comment: Thx, friend. It really helped.